# WPF: Handle a large number of routed events

Tags: wpf

I need your recomandations for the following problem:

Let say you have a MyView type (UserControl), which defines a routed event IsSelectedChanged. It is raised every time myView.IsSelected property value is changed.

Also, you have a MyContainer (Canvas), which contains a very (very!) large number of children of type MyView. MyContainer has routed event MyViewsSelectionChanged, that is raised whenever MyViewsSelection is changed. MyViewsSelection is a set of MyView objects that have IsSelected property set to **true**. MyContainer will handle MyView.IsSelectedChanged for every child and will provide its MyViewSelection status to the MyContainerParent (Panel)

MyContainerParent will handle myContainer.MyViewsSelectionChanged event

The issue I am afraid of is that my application will under-perform for a very large selection of MyView objects, resulting in a sort of 'wildfire' of events.

Any recomandations to prevent the issue, will be much appreciated!

Thanks

**some code:**

BatchView.IsSelectedChanged (MyView):

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent IsSelectedChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "IsSelectedChanged", 
        RoutingStrategy.Direct, 
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
        typeof(BatchView)
    );
/// <summary>
/// Occurs when IsSelected property value is changed.
/// </summary>
public event RoutedEventHandler IsSelectedChanged {
        add { AddHandler(IsSelectedChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(IsSelectedChangedEvent, value); }
    }
void RaiseIsSelectionChangedEvent() {
        RoutedEventArgs e = new RoutedEventArgs(IsSelectedChangedEvent, this.BatchViewModel);
        RaiseEvent(e);
        Logger.Debug("IsSelectionChanged: {0}; IsSelected = {1}", this.BatchViewModel.Description, this.IsSelected);
    }
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(BatchView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(delegate(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
        BatchView view = sender as BatchView;
        bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(args.NewValue);
        if ( view != null ) {
            view._border.BorderBrush = isSelected ? Brushes.Magenta : Brushes.Black;
            view.IsPrimarySelected = view.IsFocused && isSelected;
        }
    })));
/// <summary>
/// Get/set whether this batch view is selected
/// </summary>
public bool IsSelected {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set {
            if ( IsSelected != value ) {
                SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
                RaiseIsSelectionChangedEvent();
            }
        }
    }
```

GanttView (MyContainer):

```
static GanttView() {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(BatchView), BatchView.IsSelectedChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) {
            var batchView = sender as BatchView;
            var ganttView = batchView.FindVisualParent<GanttView>();
            if ( ganttView != null ) {
                ganttView.RaiseBatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent();
            }
            args.Handled = true;
        }));
    }

public static readonly RoutedEvent BatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "BatchViewsSelectionChanged",
        RoutingStrategy.Direct,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof(GanttView)
    );
public event RoutedEventHandler BatchViewsSelectionChanged {
        add { AddHandler(BatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(BatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent, value); }
    }
void RaiseBatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent() {
        RoutedEventArgs e = new RoutedEventArgs(BatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent, this);         
        RaiseEvent(e);
        Logger.Debug("BatchViewsSelectionChanged: {0};", this.SelectedBatchViews.Count());
    }
```

SchedulerView (MyContainerParent):

```
static SchedulerView() {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(GanttView), GanttView.BatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) {              
            var schedulerView = ((GanttView)sender).FindVisualParent<SchedulerView>();
            if ( schedulerView != null ) {
                if ( schedulerView.BatchesSelectionChanged != null ) {
                    BatchesSelectionChangedEventArgs e = new BatchesSelectionChangedEventArgs();
                    e.SelectedBatchesCount = schedulerView.GanttView.SelectedBatchViews.Count();
                    e.TotalBatchesDuration = schedulerView.GanttView.SelectedBatchViews.Sum<BatchView>(bv => bv.BatchViewModel.Model.Duration);
                    e.TotalBatchesQuantity = schedulerView.GanttView.SelectedBatchViews.Sum<BatchView>(bv => bv.BatchViewModel.Model.Quantity);
                    schedulerView.BatchesSelectionChanged(schedulerView, e);
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: First recommendation: test it, and find out whether it's really an issue.  Premature optimisation is never a good thing!

Comment: Thanks Dan. Agree with you. But in my case we are talking about thousands of views that will raise IsSelectedChanged. I think that it is obvious that I will run into the problem. What I am looking for is a good design pattern for my problem.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious at all.  Your processor is likely running at a few million cycles per second.  Ten thousand events thrown in a second needn't be a problem.

Comment: Dan, I've made the following test: Have selected 400 myViews. MyContainer received 400 IsSelectedChanged events and raise another 400 MyViewsSelectionChanged events. So, I have 800 calls for only one listener(MyContainerParent) performed in almost 1s. I am afraid that it is not acceptable. What I would like is to have 401 calls, instead of 800.

Comment: So, what's happening in your handlers?  If you post some code you'll get a more specific response.

Comment: Dan, I've added some code as requested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the number of events you have to process. You should re-evaluate your approach. Is there a way to determine when the user has finished selecting the items?

If there is no way of reducing the number of events then you might want to implement a throttle, i.e. you only process an event if no event has been received for a certain amount of time.

You can implement this yourself - e.g. by using a timer - or you can use the reactive extensions' (RX) Throttle function.

> Throttle "Ignores the values from an observable sequence which are
>   followed by another value before due time with the specified source
>   and dueTime"

You can find the RX at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx and the documentation for Trottle at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229298%28v=vs.103%29. Obviously you can also install RX via NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share the solution to my problem. Solution is based on recomandation given by my manager and Obalix. So, I will use a timer, to delay a bit the raising of GanttView.BacthViewsSelectionChangedEvent.

```
static GanttView() {            
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(BatchView),   BatchView.IsSelectedChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) {
            var batchView = sender as BatchView;
            var ganttView = batchView.FindVisualParent<GanttView>();
            if ( ganttView != null && !ganttView._batchViewIsSelectedChangedEventQueued ) {
                ganttView._batchViewIsSelectedChangedEventQueued = true;
                System.Timers.Timer eventTrigger = new System.Timers.Timer(100) { AutoReset = false };
                eventTrigger.Start();
                eventTrigger.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(delegate(object timer, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
                    ganttView._batchViewIsSelectedChangedEventQueued = false;
                    ganttView.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { ganttView.RaiseBatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent(); }), DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
                });             
            }
            args.Handled = true;
        }));
}
```

It is important to use the Dispatcher property for invokation of ganttView.RaiseBatchViewsSelectionChangedEvent(), otherwise you will get an exception (" The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."), please refer to this post http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

Dan and Obalix, thank you a lot for your time and considerations!